# Prove or disprove the set forms a group under addition

Tags: group-theory

Consider the set $H = \{\frac{a}{2^n}:a \in \mathbb{Z}, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, I need to prove or disprove that H forms a group under addition.

I tried to check the closure, associativity, identity, and inverse. I'm not sure about the inverse part and the closure part.

For closure, let $x$, $y \in H$, there exist $a$, $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x=\frac{a}{2^n}$ and  $y =\frac{b}{2^m}$. We have $x + y =\frac{a}{2^n}+\frac{b}{2^m}=\frac{2^ma+2^nb}{2^m2^n}$ . I think it also belongs to $H$.

For inverse, I write $-x =-\frac{a}{2^n}=\frac{-a}{2^n}$, which belongs to $H$.

I skip the associativity and identity parts here, since I pretty sure it's right. Then I conclude $H$ is a group.

Anyone have some hints for me? Appreciate any help!

Comment: Seems right. Closure and inverse is satisfied

Comment: Another way to think of this is that you have taken the *ring* of integers and inverted the prime $2$.  The resulting ring is called the "integers localized away from $2$" and can be denoted $\mathbb{Z}[\frac12]$ and is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @TonyPizza@AlgTop1854 Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $x \in H$, then $x$ shall be of the form $\frac{a}{2^n}$ where $a \in Z$ and $n \in N_0$. The expression you have arrived for proving closure property, Note the denominator and numerator terms, Does the expression now qualifies to be an element of H?

Similarly, Note the denominator and numerator of the expression you have arrived for proving every element of H has an inverse in H.